# What was the bulk of Starfleet ships doing in the Laurentian system?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-2009

Stated in *Star Trek* (2009) movie that Starfleet had the primary bulk of the fleet engaged in the Laurentian system. Was there ever any information why this was?

Comment: The comic book Star Trek: Nero suggested the Laurentian system was the location of Rura Penthe, and the Federation responded to a Klingon distress call after Nero destroyed 47 Klingon warbirds.

Comment: They were busy maintaining the plot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The bulk of the Federation fleet was supposedly offering support to the Klingon fleet currently in distress. (A bit strange or unusual considering the posture of the Federation and Klingon Empire in the Star Trek: Into Darkness.)

From Memory Alpha:

> A deleted scene from the film establishes that the Narada was crippled after it was rammed by the Kelvin. A convoy of Klingon warbirds eventually arrived and captured the ship and its crew. Twenty five years later, Nero and his crew escaped from their imprisonment on Rura Penthe, reclaimed the Narada, used the ship to destroy 47 Klingon warbirds, and continued on their mission.

Comment: Actually sounds like one of the cut features I won't miss. The klingons had that ship for 25 years and did nothing with it? Doesn't sound like something I'd expect or believe straight away.

Comment: The Klingon scenes really could have given some depth to the whole "did nothing for 25 years" though. This was answered in a previous question of mine.